# how to setup django with apache 2.4 and python3

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache

I am using amazon ec2. I have installed httpd 2.4 python3, pip3. Here is my script which I use to set up.

```
#!/bin/bash

yum update -y
yum install httpd httpd-devel python3 python3-pip git gcc python3-devel -y
cd /var/www/html

groupadd www
usermod -a -G www apache
usermod -a -G www ec2-user

cd /opt
mkdir django
chmod ug+s /opt/django
chmod ug+wr -R /opt/django
cd /opt/django
chown -hR apache:www /opt/django

su ec2-user -c 'cd /opt/django; sudo pip3 install virtualenv mod_wsgi'
su ec2-user -c ''


su ec2-user -c 'virtualenv -p python3 connect_api'
su ec2-user -c 'sudo git clone https://copyrepo'

chmod ug+s /opt/django
chmod ug+wr -R /opt/django
chown -hR apache:www /opt/django

su ec2-user -c 'cd /opt/django/api; source ../connect_api/bin/activate; sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt'
su ec2-user -c 'cd /opt/django/api; source ../connect_api/bin/activate; sudo pip3 install django'
yum remove -y gcc python3-devel httpd-devel
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
echo LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so > /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf
su ec2-user -c 'echo export SECRET_KEY=al3^qak1limt+3l%*rtk1elula*$z^%a9wt+oao%mri$u3qhya >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export DEBUG=1 >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export EMAIL_BACKEND=django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export ENVIRONMENT=local >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export ALLOWED_HOSTS=[10.0.0.0/24,domainaws] >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export DATABASE_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export DATABASE_NAME=dbname >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export DATABASE_USER=user >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export DATABASE_PASSWORD=xxx >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export DATABASE_HOST=domain >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export DATABASE_PORT=5432 >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=1 >> ~/.bashrc'
su ec2-user -c 'echo export HASHID_SALT=MFswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD >> ~/.bashrc'

cd /opt/django/
source connect_api/bin/activate
cd api
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py collectstatic

chmod ug+wr -R /opt/django
chown -hR apache:www /opt/django

cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/
cat <<EOT >> connect-api.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sharif@hci.digital

    DocumentRoot /opt/django/api/connect/

    ErrorLog logs/error_log

    CustomLog logs/access_log combined

    Alias /static /opt/django/api/connect/static

    <Directory /opt/django/api/connect/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /opt/django/api/connect>
       <Files wsgi.py>
           Require all granted
       </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess connect_api python-path=/opt/django/api:/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup connect_api
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/api/connect/wsgi.py

    SetEnv SECRET_KEY ${SECRET_KEY}
    SetEnv DEBUG ${DEBUG}
    SetEnv EMAIL_BACKEND ${EMAIL_BACKEND}
    SetEnv ENVIRONMENT ${ENVIRONMENT}
    SetEnv ALLOWED_HOSTS ${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
    SetEnv DATABASE_ENGINE ${DATABASE_ENGINE}
    SetEnv DATABASE_NAME ${DATABASE_NAME}
    SetEnv DATABASE_USER ${DATABASE_USER}
    SetEnv DATABASE_PASSWORD ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    SetEnv DATABASE_HOST ${DATABASE_HOST}
    SetEnv DATABASE_PORT ${DATABASE_PORT}
    SetEnv CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL ${CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL}
    SetEnv HASHID_SALT ${HASHID_SALT}
</VirtualHost>
EOT

sed -i 's/Group apache/Group www/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
chown -hR apache:www /var/run/httpd
su ec2-user -c 'source ~/.bashrc; sudo service httpd start'
su ec2-user -c 'sudo chkconfig httpd on'
```

If i run as root just for testing `(connect_api) [root@ip-10-0-1-52 api]# ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` it works. but when i use apache it errors with

```
     application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/django/api/connect/settings.py", line 261, in <module>
     HASHIDS = Hashids(salt=os.environ.get('HASHID_SALT'), min_length=10, alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
   File "/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hashids.py", line 190, in __init__
     separators = _reorder(separators, salt)
   File "/opt/django/connect_api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hashids.py", line 68, in _reorder
     len_salt = len(salt)
 TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: maybe that you have big and small letters in salt you have got some problem, try "salt_letters" for it

Comment: for the apache user have you set up the suer env so that this is set `salt=os.environ.get('HASHID_SALT')`

Comment: I have `HASHIDS = Hashids(salt=os.environ.get('HASHID_SALT'), min_length=10, alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")` in `connect/settings.py`

Comment: I have also added exports to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

Comment: but in the os env of apache user have you set `HASHID_SALT`

Comment: if your referring to default apache user, I have not. won't that mean i have to create home dir etc etc?

Comment: this line `HASHIDS = Hashids(salt=os.environ.get('HASHID_SALT'), min_length=10, alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")` is trying to readh a value from the os users enviroemnt which you have not set up

Comment: I added exports to `/usr/share/httpd/.bashrc` which is apache home dir. when I sudo to apache user i can see it in the env using `export`. same error message though. `apache:x:48:48:Apache:/usr/share/httpd:/bin/bash`

Comment: And how are you starting the service?

Comment: I start service as root `service httpd start`